# Find items within <li> tags using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, findelement

I've tried to find the element item (eg. *Item1, Item2, Item3*, and *Item4*) within the 'li' tag using Selenium, but an error happened with this message:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element
```

How do I find the items within the 'li' tag element?

```
elms = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='product-list')
```

or

```
elms = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='product-list']")
```

Web source:

```
<div class='product'> 
 <div class='menuList1'> Menu1 Menu2</div>
 <div class='menuList2'> aaa </div>
 <ul id='productDetail' class='product-list'> 
  <li class='product-list detail' id='1'> Item1</li> 
  <li class='product-list detail' id='2'> Item2</li> 
  <li class='product-list detail' id='3'> Item3</li> 
  <li class='product-list detail' id='4'> Item4</li> 
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think since the element is under menu tab it is not visible you need to click/hover on menu and then identify the element. Could you please post an image to ensure I assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) you have tried were a bit errorprone. The desired elements are within `<li>` having *class* attribute as *`product-list detail`*

```
<div class='product'> 
    <div class='menuList1'> Menu1 Menu2</div>
    <div class='menuList2'> aaa </div>
         <ul id='productDetail' class='product-list'> 
              <li class='product-list detail' id='1'> Item1</li> 
              <li class='product-list detail' id='2'> Item2</li> 
              <li class='product-list detail' id='3'> Item3</li> 
              <li class='product-list detail' id='4'> Item4</li> 
         </ul>
    </div>
```

---

### Solution

To find the elements within the `<li>` tags you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  elms = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product div.menuList2 > ul.product-list li.product-list.detail")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  elms = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product']//div[@class='menuList2']/ul[@class='product-list']//li[@class='product-list detail']")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list of elements:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//li[@class='product-list detail']")

for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```